# Use nested navigators with react-navigation and redux integration

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying to use nested navigators with a redux integration, but the app fails to load with the following error:

[image: Error]

Everything was working fine until I added a second layer of navigators for the login flow.

How can I accomplish this?

Here is the complete code for the navigator and integrating it with redux:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

import { dogTypes } from '../ducks/dog';

import { StackNavigator, addNavigationHelpers, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import { createReduxBoundAddListener, createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';

import MainScreen from '../screens/MainScreen';
import SecondScreen from '../screens/SecondScreen';
import AuthLoadingScreen from '../screens/AuthLoadingScreen';
import AuthScreen from '../screens/AuthScreen';

import HeaderWithMenu from '../components/Headers/HeaderWithMenu';
import HeaderWithBack from '../components/Headers/HeaderWithBack';

import Translations from '../translations/screens';

const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
  LoginFlow: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      Auth: AuthScreen,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    })
  },
  MainFlow: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      Main: {
        screen: MainScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          header: <HeaderWithMenu title={Translations.t('mainScreen')}/>
        })
      },
      Second: { 
        screen: SecondScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          header: <HeaderWithBack title={Translations.t('secondScreen')} navigation={navigation}/>
        })
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Main'
    })
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'MainFlow'
});

const initialState = fromJS(
  {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {
        index: 0,
        key: 'MainFlow',
        routeName: 'MainFlow',
        routes: [
          {
            key: 'Main',
            routeName: 'Main'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
);

export const mainNavReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case dogTypes.DOG_BIGGER:
      nextState = state.merge(MainNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
        MainNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Second'),
        state.toJS()
      ));
      break;
    default:
      nextState = state.merge(MainNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state.toJS()));
      break;
  }

  // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
  return nextState || state;
};

export const mainNavMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  "root",
  state => state.nav,
)

const addListener = createReduxBoundAddListener("root");

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
  }
  onBackPress = () => {
    const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
    if (nav.index === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
    return true;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MainNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
        dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
        state: this.props.nav,
        addListener,
      })} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    nav: state.get('nav').toJS()
  }
};

export const MainNavigatorComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was actually something in react-navigation library directly. I updated my version to the latest (2.0.0-rc.1 at this time) and it solved the issue.

I still liked the way @NewToCoding defined his navigators and had to change the initialState a bit. Here is the final working code:

```
const LoginFlow = StackNavigator({
  Auth: AuthScreen,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Auth',
});

const MainFlow = StackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: MainScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: <HeaderWithMenu title={Translations.t('mainScreen')}/>
    })
  },
  Second: { 
    screen: SecondScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: <HeaderWithBack title={Translations.t('secondScreen')} navigation={navigation}/>
    })
  },
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Main'
});

const MainNavigator = SwitchNavigator({
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  App: MainFlow,
  Auth: LoginFlow,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
});

const initialState = fromJS(MainNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'AuthLoading' })));

export const mainNavReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case dogTypes.DOG_BIGGER:
      nextState = state.merge(MainNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Second' }),
        state.toJS()
      ));
      break;
    default:
      nextState = state.merge(MainNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state.toJS()));
      break;
  }

  // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
  return nextState || state;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

StackNavigator should be defined on its own, and each StackNavigator needs to be defined before you define its nested location.

So how I would do it is:

```
const LoginFlow = StackNavigator({})

const MainFlow = StackNavigator({})

const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginFlow //screen is the stack navigator defined above
  },
  Main: {
    screen: MainFlow //screen is the stack navigator defined above
  }
```

})

Also your initial state is in correct please read the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration.html#step-by-step-guide) and you can literally just copy paste the way they set up their reducers/store and integrated with redux.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The issue was actually something in the library itself, and got fixed in one the beta releases (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/3902). I'll create an answer summarizing everything.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue of React Navigation. I just changed the React Navigation version on my package.json. I spent a lot of hours to solve it Do this:
Instead of this

```
"react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^2.0.9",
```

I changed it to this

```
"react-navigation": "2.18.2",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^2.0.9",
```